# Drawing circles on map using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-2, circle

I want to draw circles of certain radius on a map using openlayers . But the latitude,longitude & radius values are given in a excel sheet.

How do I do this work in OpenLayers?

I heard that OpenLayers doesn't take data from excel sheet so to which format I have to change my excel file?

And how to draw circles on the map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Circles in Openlayers**

http://geographika.co.uk/samples/geodesic/

http://geographika.co.uk/creating-a-geodesic-circle-in-openlayers
you will need your data in json - Google Spreadsheets can do this

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/key/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc
```

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html

Comment: It's perhaps a bit too complicated to draw geodetic polygons. Here is a demo using MapFish client (so OpenLayers) : http://demo.mapfish.org/mapfishsample/1.2/examples/geostat/proportionalSymbols.html

Comment: You can find a basic OpenLayers text layer example here: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/markersTextLayer.html   It is based on this simple text file:  http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/textfile.txt

Comment: Geographika link is dead @Mapperz

Answer (score 2):

It has a built in function called createRegularPolygon that can be used like this:

```
var circle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0),
    1,
    30
);
```