# circle with dfferent colours representing different criteria

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I want to draw circles on maps with different colours, this gives the signal strength of the tower, suppose circle is of 50 m then first 20m should be given a color1 and next 20 m color2 and remaining color3.

Is this possible in Geoserver SLD or openlayers? How?

Comment: I think you might google ringed buffer if you don't get a response that helps.

Comment: Here you go: http://tinyurl.com/3flc4z5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [that](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/drawing-circles-on-map-using-openlayers)! *Someone* has already asked for [drawing circles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/drawing-circles-on-map-using-openlayers) and it has already been answered.

Regarding colors, you should use *OpenLayers.Style();* and have a look on [OL doc](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html) and eventually on the wiki [page](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Styles).